# How to get the word corresponding to highest tf-idf using PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, tf-idf

I've seen similar posts but with no complete answer, hence posting here.

I am using TF-IDF in Spark to get the word within a document which has the maximum tf-idf value. I use the following piece of code.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer, CountVectorizer, StopWordsRemover

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="doc_cln", outputCol="tokens")
remover1 = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="tokens", 
outputCol="stopWordsRemovedTokens")

stopwordList =["word1","word2","word3"]

remover2 = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="stopWordsRemovedTokens", 
outputCol="filtered" ,stopWords=stopwordList)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=2000)

idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features", minDocFreq=5)

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, remover1, remover2, hashingTF, idf])

model = pipeline.fit(df)

results = model.transform(df)
results.cache()
```

I get results like

```
|[a8g4i9g5y, hwcdn] |(2000,[905,1104],[7.34977707433047,7.076179741760428])
```

where

```
filtered: array (nullable = true)
features: vector (nullable = true)
```

How can I get the array extracted from "feature"? Ideally, I would like to get the word corresponding to the highest tfidf, like below

```
|a8g4i9g5y|7.34977707433047
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you can't assume the word `a8g4i9g5y` is the one associated with feature 905 and, therefore, has tf-idf value of 7.34977707433047. The hashing process does not necessarily maintain the order of the words in this specific sentence. You can only be sure that either `a8g4i9g5y` or `hwcdn` are represented by column 905, while the other is represented by `1104`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your `feature` column has type `vector` from package `pyspark.ml.linalg`. It could be either

   1. `pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector` ([source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/linalg.html#DenseVector)), e.g. `DenseVector([1., 2.])`
   2. `pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector` ([source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/linalg.html#SparseVector)), e.g. `SparseVector(4, [1, 3], [3.0, 4.0])`
2. Based on the data you have `(2000,[905,1104],[7.34977707433047,7.076179741760428])`, apparently it's `SparseVector`, and it could be broken down to 3 main components:

   - `size`: `2000`
   - `indices`: `[905,1104]`
   - `values`: `[7.34977707433047,7.076179741760428]`
3. And what you're looking for is the property `values` of that vector.
4. With the other 'literal' PySpark SQL type such as `StringType` or `IntegerType`, you can access its properties (and aggregation functions) using SQL functions package ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)). However `vector` is not literal SQL type and the only way to access its properties is through an UDF, like so:

   ```py
   # Important: `vector.values` returns ndarray from numpy.
   # PySpark doesn't understand ndarray, therefore you'd want to 
   # convert it to normal Python list using `tolist`
   def extract_values_from_vector(vector):
       return vector.values.tolist()

   # Just a regular UDF
   def extract_values_from_vector_udf(col):
       return udf(extract_values_from_vector, ArrayType(DoubleType()))

   # And use that UDF to get your values
   results.select(extract_values_from_vector_udf('features'), 'features')
   ```